# How to remove credit card info from autofill that is only listed in Chrome settings but not in the Google account?

Tags: google-chrome

Payment settings in Chrome shows many old cards, but Google account only shows 1 card.

Same as this: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/11482941/remove-a-credit-card-from-autofill

Chrome settings:
[image]

Google account:
[image]

Comment: I assume you have verified you are synchronized to the correct Google Account. Those payment methods clearly indicate they are stored Google Pay payments. If they were stored by only Chrome there would be a vertical ellipsis that would allow you to remove them

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out: For some reason there are 2 "payment profiles" in my Google account. All the old cards were stored in the other payment profile.

On to figuring out how to remove that 2nd payment profile...

[image]